# How to discard row if gridview's row validation fails (devexpress)

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

In XtraGridView, from the way RowValidation works, it seems that user has no choice but first correct the values (leading to validation being successful) and then press Discard button (which I provided separately and it does RejectChanges). I want an option that user can discard the row without any pop-up alert even if row has invalid data.

In my case when user presses Discard, it leads to row validation being fired (due to focus change). The discard button event handler is suppressed, if row validation is unsuccessful. This way I am never able to simply discard the invalid row.

This is common feature anyone with a grid would need. Expecting a standard solution or a workaround.

Comment: Simply disable and enable row validation around the discard operation?

Comment: Cant do I guess. Because row validation fires before discard button click is detected. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made me curious, as you say,something as basic as that should be in there somewhere.

Bit of gooling found that waht you do is trap the InvalidRowException, it has a var argument and you can set it to ignore.

Here's where I found it.

[DevExpress](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument749)

Comment: No no. doesnt help. i think you didnt get my question. problem is that why other events like button presses etc. are suppressed if row validation is not success (i.e. when invalid data). this way i am always stuck unless i correct the data to temporarily make it valid and then only i can discard it.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you check the focused button and sidestep validation if the discard button is focused.

The general DevExpress setup forces the user to insert valid values when validating, pressing Esc is a simple solution to reset the field to the original value.